# Find min/max element in a nested map with Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have a data structure that is like below:

```
Map<StudentStatus, TreeMap<Integer, Student>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Which I can call for a student status like PHD, and it will give me a TreeMap of Integer to Student objects. This `TreeMap` holds the student IDs as keys, and Student objects as values.

```
public enum StudentStatus {
    UNDERGRAD,
    POSTGRAD,
    PHD;
}

public class Student {
    public String name;
    public int age;
}

public class StudentDetails {
    public int id;
    public StudentStatus studentStatus;
    public String name;
}
```

Now what I want to do is, get the youngest student by age, in other words search the nested map, and create a StudentDetails object from that student.
So I will need the keys of the first 2 maps. The first key is the StudentStatus, and the second key is the Student id.

In the end I will need an object like this:

```
new StudentDetails(id: 36, studentStatus: StudentStatus.PHD, name: "Anil");
```

I couldn't find a way to store these keys while streaming and create the final object with Java 8 Stream in a single statement.

I simplified the problem with Student analogy, maybe it doesn't make much sense to use such a structure for the above problem, but in my case it does.

Comment: ```StudentEnum``` or ```StudentStatus```?

Comment: Just fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add student age to `StudentDetails` class as member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build `Map.Entry` with age as key and `StudentDetails` as value. Then sort it and get first.

```java
StudentDetails studentDetails = map.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(statusEntry -> statusEntry.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                .map(ageEntry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, StudentDetails>(
                        ageEntry.getValue().getAge(),
                        new StudentDetails(
                                ageEntry.getKey(), 
                                statusEntry.getKey(), 
                                ageEntry.getValue().getName())))
        ).sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getKey))
        .findFirst()
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .get();
```

#### UPDATE

As it was written in commentary below: the last part (from 'sorted')
can be replaced with below code:

```java
        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getKey))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .get();
```

Comment: A combination of `sort().findFirst()` can be easily replaced with `min` or `max`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a corresponding `StudentDetails` given a `StudentStatus`, you can make use of `Stream#min` such as:

```
StudentDetails detailsForGivenStatus(Map<StudentStatus, TreeMap<Integer, Student>> map, StudentStatus studentStatus) {
    return map.get(studentStatus).entrySet().stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue().getAge()))
            .map(entry -> new StudentDetails(entry.getKey(), studentStatus, entry.getValue().getName()))
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```

---

Similarly, if you were looking for each status based youngest student details, you can use:

```
Map<StudentStatus, StudentDetails> statusToYoungestStudentDetail(Map<StudentStatus, TreeMap<Integer, Student>> map,
                                                                 StudentStatus studentStatus) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .min(Comparator.comparing(en -> en.getValue().getAge()))
                    .map(entry -> new StudentDetails(entry.getKey(),
                            studentStatus, entry.getValue().getName()))
                    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This alternative uses a Collector on the minimum; no sorting, runtime is in O(n).

```
var student = map.values().stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.minBy(Student::getAge))
    .get();
```

Comment: It returns the Student object instead of StudentDetails.